Prove that if $A$ and $B \backslash C$ are disjoint, then $A \cap B \subseteq C$
My proof: Suppose $x$ is arbitrary, and for all $x$, $A \cap B \backslash C =\varnothing $. Suppose $x$ is an element of $A \cap B$; it follows that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Suppose $x \notin C$; it follows that there is a $x$ where $x$ is an element of both $A$ and $B$ but not $C$, hence contradicting the statement that $A \cap B \backslash C =\varnothing$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, it can be concluded that for all $x$,  $A \cap B \subseteq C$
I am new to proofs and have a hard time converting my proofs to 'words'. Please let me know if there are any flaws in my logic. Thanks!

Looks good to me.

You are right!!

What does $\land$ mean and how is it different from $\cap$?

Your proof is basically right but it is a bit confusing because there are extraneous phrases such as "for all $x$" followed by a statement that doesn't involve $x$, and "there exists an $x$" when $x$ has already been chosen. Here is how I would edit it to be clearer.

Suppose $A$ and $B\setminus C$ are disjoint. Let $x$ be any element of $A\cap B$; it follows that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Suppose $x\notin C$; since $x\in B$ it follows that $x\in B\setminus C$. But, since $x\in A$, this contradicts our assumption that $A$ and $B\setminus C$ are disjoint. Thus $x\in C$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $A\cap B$, we conclude that $A\cap B\subseteq C$.


As stated in the comments your proof is fine.
An option:
Given $A\cap$$(B$ \ $C) =\emptyset$
$B=(B$ \ $C) \cup (B\cap C) $ (Why?)
$A\cap B =$
$ A\cap ((B$ \ $C) \cup (B\cap C)) $
$A\cap B=$
$(A\cap (B$ \ $C))\cup(A\cap B\cap C)$
$A\cap B=$
$ (A\cap B\cap C)=(A \cap B) \cap C$
Interpret the last statement.
